Angular animations - make div move right some amount on each click
How to, given div in angular animations, make it move right some amount (px) on each click?
This is the demo of what I have in mind:
https://jsfiddle.net/ergsLju1/23/
Same example in jQuery:
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('div').animate({ left: '+=25px'  })
});


You could use Angular animations, but for this task the easiest way is to just use CSS transitions and property binding.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
<button (click)="leftOffset = leftOffset + 25">Move</button>
<div [ngStyle]="{'left': leftOffset + 'px'}">&nbsp;</div>`,
  styles: [
    `
button {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

div {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 200ms ease;
}
`,
  ],
})
export class App {
  leftOffset = 0;
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ukvd4c?file=src%2Fmain.ts

yeah, so they say, that one should go for CSS whenever possible when it comes to animations/transitions because animations/transitions are faster/better in css
